# my Python mini game. It confuses me :-(

Tags: python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and learning Python The Hard Way book.

However, I got some creative ideas and I want to make some changes in this exercise: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

So I wrote my own code:

```
from sys import exit

times_in_exchange_path = 0
asked_for_help = 0

def exchange_path():
    print "Hola! You are about to get to the very dangerous point, kid!"
    print "You are independent from now. With luck..."

    action = raw_input('...')

    if 'what' in action:
        print 'I said you are on your own now. No one is gonna help you',
        print "with anything..."
        exchange_path()
    elif 'creepy' in action:
        print "I found it creepy, too. Kid. Take me out of here with you."
        print "Is that OK?"
        haunted = False

        decision = raw_input()

        if decision == 'agree':
            print "Finally. I'm free!"
            haunted = True
            times_in_exchange_path = times_in_exchange_path + 1
            start()
        else:
            dead("I will make you know what pain really is!!?! >:(")

    else:
        dead("A shadow barged into you, and you broke your neck.")

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        how_much = int(choice)
    except:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"

        if haunted:
            print "\nHowever... I can't just let you get away easily like this."
            print '"Why??" - I asked'
            print "You belong to the gold mine now!!"
            print '"What do you mean??" - I replied in fear'
            print "Power requires sacrifice. Muhahahhaha!"
            dead(" ")
        else:
            exit(0)

    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard! It's a trap for you!")

def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?\n"
    bear_moved = False

    if haunted:
        print "...Wait. The bear suddenly shouts at you, break the window",
        print "and runs far far away."
        print "Let's go to the door, kid...\n\n"
        gold_room()
    else:
        while True:
            choice = raw_input("> ")

            if choice == "take honey":
                dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
            elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
                print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through",
                print "it now."
                bear_moved = True
            elif choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
                dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
            elif choice == "open door" and bear_moved:
                gold_room()
            else:
                print "I got no idea what that means."


def cthulhu_room():
    print "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
    print "He, it, whatever stares at you and goes insane."
    print "Do you flee for your life or he eats your head?"
    cthulhu_dead = False

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if cthulhu_dead:
        print "There's nothing here, kid. Except of the light and a dead body."
        print "Let's go!\n...\n\n"
        start()
    else:

        if "flee" in choice:
            start()
        elif "head" in choice:
            dead("Well that was tasty!")
        elif "fight" in choice:

            if haunted:
                print "With mysterious distraction, the Cthulhu turns his back",
                print "at you. You use the shiny magical spear nearby to kill",
                print "the monster."
                cthulhu_dead = True
                print "\n...\n"
                start()
            else:
                dead("Awesome tasty head you have!")

        else:
            cthulhu_room()


def dead(why):
    print why, "\n\nGood job! You died."
    exit(0)


def first_assist():
    asked_for_help += 1

    if asked_for_help in range(4, 6):
        print "Stop! You are attracting them!"
        print "A portal shows up and you are walking into it...\n\n"
    elif asked_for_help > 5:
        dead("Those demons rise from the ground. And burn you down!")
    else:
        print "Hi! I am your beautiful assistance."
        print "As you got lost in here, I will show you the way."
        print "You have to know that all three paths are dangerous, and there",
        print "is no way out of here.\nSo, try to survive with glory."
        print '"left", "right" and "front" are the first three spells you use.'
        print "There's a mighty power near here. Have a pure heart, and know",
        print "that you will never have to touch that evil power..."
        print "Good luck from here... Be wise."
    start()


def start():
    print "You are in a dark room."
    print "There is a door to your right and left."
    print 'And a middle path, full of darkness, in front of you.'
    print "Which one do you dare to take?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif choice == "right":
        cthulhu_room()
    elif choice == "front":

        if times_in_exchange_path == 0:
            exchange_path()
        else:
            print "You feel something stopping you from entering this place. \n"
            start()

    elif "help" in choice:
        first_assist()
    else:
        dead("You stumble around the room until you starve.")


start()
```

But for some reasons, my code doesn't work properly.

It first prints out to the screen the lines like this:

> You are in a dark room.
>
> There is a door to your right and left
>
> And a middle path, full of darkness
>
> Which one do you dare to take?

And then, whatever I type in, the program rises errors. I don't know why.

Please help me fix this game.

Thank you very very much. :-)

Comment: In what way does it not work properly? Does it give you an error message? Is it hanging? Is it causing general mayhem and raising of the dead?

Comment: Ah, yes. the old `cause('mayhem')` and `dead.raise()` situation. Hate when that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when you're asking a question, you should include the error messages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 174, in <module>
    start()
  File "game.py", line 159, in start
    cthulhu_room()
  File "game.py", line 120, in cthulhu_room
    cthulhu_room()
  File "game.py", line 104, in cthulhu_room
    start()
  File "game.py", line 159, in start
    cthulhu_room()
  File "game.py", line 104, in cthulhu_room
    start()
  File "game.py", line 157, in start
    bear_room()
  File "game.py", line 66, in bear_room
    if haunted:
NameError: global name 'haunted' is not defined
```

This is the error that is got when I took a right after fleeing Cthulhu.

The issue here is that `haunted` is defined inside of the function `exchange_path`. The problems is that variables defined inside functions are local to that function, and can't be used inside other functions. Doing so results in two unqiue variables (albeit having the same name).

The simple solution (although not recommended) is to define `haunted` in the outer most scope, at the very start of the script along with `asked_for_help` and `times_in_exchange_path`, and then use the keyword `global` to tell python that the variable `haunted` is actually a global variable and not a local variable.

```
...
asked_for_help = 0
haunted = False    # Or False, whatever you choose

def exchange_path():
    global haunted
    ...
    if haunted:
        ...
```

Generally, global variable are discouraged and you should instead pass variables as parameters instead.